# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql

I am running into the error in the title when I try to connect insert values into my database.  my debug errors out at:

> using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(myConString))

Here is the error from VS2013:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=Format of the initialization string does not conform to
>   specification starting at index 153.   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String
>   connStr)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>          at MD5_Loader.MainForm.btn_Upload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\xxxx\MD5
>   Loader\MD5 Loader\MainForm.cs:line 43
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at MD5_Loader.Program.Main() in d:\Dropbox\Bots\World of Warcraft\MD5Loader\MD5 Loader\MD5 Loader\Program.cs:line 19
>   InnerException:

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MD5_Loader
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private const string Server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        private const string Port = "3306";
        private const string Md5DataBase = "database";
        private const string Md5Table= "Builds";
        private const string DbUser = "admin";
        private const string DbPass = "admin";
        private string _fileName = "";
        private string _md5 = "";

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Variable for MySQL server Connection
                const string myConString = "Server=" + Server + ";" +
                                           "PORT=" + Port + ";" +
                                           "DATABASE=" + Md5DataBase + ";" +
                                           "Persist Security Info=No;" +
                                           "Encrypt=True;" +
                                           "SslMode=Required;" +
                                           "username=" + DbUser + ";" +
                                           "password=" + DbPass + ";";
                MessageBox.Show(tbx_Revision.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                                CheckMd5(tbx_FileName.Text) + Environment.NewLine +
                                         Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tbx_FileName.Text));
                using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(myConString))
                {
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO " + Md5Table +
                        "(Revision, CheckSum, Product) " +
                        "VALUES (@Revision, @CheckSum, @Product)",
                        conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revision", tbx_Revision.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckSum", CheckMd5(tbx_FileName.Text));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tbx_FileName.Text));
                        conn.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            cmd.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your connection string is invalid from character index 153.  I suggest that you look at the contents of that connection string and determine what is at that position.  Make sure that what you have conforms to what's suggested at www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: @JonH What is the value of `myConString` when your code generates the above exception? It could be something specific to the parameters you're using. In particular at character 153. If you're going to edit out the string to remove sensitive data please highlight where character 153 is.

Comment: @Alex:  Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;PORT=3306;DATABASE=database;Persist Security Info=No;Encrypt=True;SslMode=Required;username=admin;password=admin;

Edit:  I am able to Navicat into it with the credentials.  I also doubled checked and cut and pasted them in to make sure it was not that.

Comment: After getting the connection string like you asked and just running that in the new MySqlConnection() it is coming up as my username.  I will delve into that a bit.  I checked the server and the username *should* be valid, but I digress.

Edit:  Just recreated the user and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I verified the user and pass work through Navicat.  I am at a loss why it will work with Navicat but not work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer comes in the form of the password.  The generated password that came from the hosting site  contained a ";" in the password.  This caused error with in the connection string.  I appreciate everyone's help.  Sometimes having to sanitize the questions prohibits the right answer.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score -2):

add the following codes in web.config

```
  <appSettings>   
    <add key="ConSecMode" value="OPEN"/>
  </appSettings>
```