# C# Unhandled Argument Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I am getting an error and this is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace dbgen
{
       static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-7AN9GF5;Database=Velocity;Trusted_Connection=true";
                    // using the code here...
                    conn.ConnectionString = "connection_string";
                    conn.Open();

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    // Pool A is created.
                }

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=pubs"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    // Pool B is created because the connection strings differ.
                }

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    // The connection string matches pool A.
                }
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new mainform());
        }
}
       }
```

I am using a Visual Studio 2013 to connect to the database to Velocity [Database name] on the SQL Server Express. And here is the screenshot of the error.

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izzo3.png)

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797017/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-argumentexception-occurred-in-system-dat)

Comment: The interesting part of an exception is what you see when you click "view detail". An ArgumentException occurs (usually) when something happens as the result of passing bad data in as an argument. But, the intersection stuff is usually in the Message property (and in the InnerException property, if it's not null). You can see the current exception in the Watch window by inspecting the $exception pseudo variable. Oh, and you can copy/paste exception details as text.

Comment: Images of exceptions are useless. Also, they a good reason for downvote (see [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)). So please, replace it with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Connection String is malformed.
why don't you use :

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-7AN9GF5;Database=Velocity;Trusted_Connection=true";
```

Comment: Yes. I removed the other SqlConnection in the code. I used only the ConnectionString that you said and it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a correct connection string to "conn.ConnectionString".
"connection_string" is not a connection string, should be like "Server=xxx;Database=xxx;".